# Login Form on MDI Form

Tags: vb6

i have a login form in VB 6.0. My requirement is that when i run the project, the login form should come on top of the MDI form. Can any one please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the Login form as MDI child. And set show it a Form Dialog mode.

Comment: You can call LoginForm.ShowDialog() - Call it from MDI.

Comment: But that is in VB.NET, i dont think that there is ShowDialog() in VB 6.0

Comment: @George: No, there's no `ShowDialog` method. You specify modality as an argument to the `Show` method. The simplest way is using the `vbModal` constant. It's not clear why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, you need to call Show method with vbModel constant. Thanks to Code Gray :)

Answer (score 0):

in the `MDI Form` `Load / Activated` event

```
LoginForm.Show vbModal
```

Comment: This will only show the login form. I want the MDI form to be also open in the background.

Comment: First you need to Show the MDI Form and in the Acitvated Event of MDI Form Call the Above Code